# How to gain access to "this" variable in INRIA-SPOON

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, inria-spoon

I'm working with INRIA Spoon.

I have some dynamic methods invocations like the following one:

```
a.doSomething();
```

I can obtain to the *variable access* `a` using the `getTarget()` method of the `CtInvocation` instance. My task is to generate code to store `a` into file. To do so, I need the type and source position (class name, line, etc) of `a` so I can generate code like `logger.logSerializable(a, "My.Class:21")` or like `logger.logDoubleArrayList(a, "My.otherClass:23)"`.

So far so good, I managed to do this just fine by acquiring the result of the `getTarget` method of a `CtInvocation` instance. However, when the invocation's target is equal `this`, like for example:

```
doSomething(); // equivalent to -> this.doSomething();
```

the `getTarget` returns *null*.

How can I get the `this` *variable access* one given `CtInvocation` is targeting?

Comment: which version do you use? in the latest one, getTarget should not return null but rather a CtThisAccess.

Comment: I was using 4.2, but I can change to 5.2. Anyway your comment just answered my question, thanks!

Comment: When you switch the Spoon version to 5.2, you should have a `CtThisAccess` marked as implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking for targets (`getTarget`) instance of `CtThisAccess` or by directly processing `CtThisAccess`